# Java: Check if a java.lang.Runtime was successfull with junit4

Tags: java, junit, runtime

I would like to by means of a JUnit 4 test class check whether a runtime has been successfully carried out and open.

The runtime is initialized as follows:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
```

The function `.exec` starts an instance. I want to check whether this was also successful.

But I don't know as right how i can check this. Has one of you an idea?

Greetings

p.s. Sorry for this realy bad english

Comment: You'll have to consume the program's standard output and to get the exit status, use `waitFor` method.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoTopolnik this has helped me